# Python: just can't add a new line to my file

Tags: python, csv, line

i know this has been asked so many times, and i tried about 20 different ways to make it work, but my code won't add a new line to my csv file, it just overwrites the first line all the time (the first line is written properly):

```
        string = str(data["message"]["id"]) + "," + str(data["message"]["date"])
        f = open('myfile.csv', 'w')
        f.write(string)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
```

EDIT : As proposed below, solved by changing 'w' for 'a' in open() command above. So append instead of write.

Comment: Python 3.6 under windows

Comment: Test if your string is actually a <str> object. Try print(type(string)) and let us know what is it showing. I don't see any other issue with the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the file in `append` mode not `write` mode.

change

```
f = open('myfile.csv', 'w')
```

to

```
f = open('myfile.csv', 'a')
```